# How do I get the 2nd key in the level 5?

Tags: vim-adventures

I think I will be a word puzzle on the place just before the second chest but cannot sort it out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk to the kid on the text before the first door (he'd appear after the text is completed on the upper right corner) and he'll give you a hint. The hint refers to the text with the 'X'. Check out the first letter of each line.